# How to keep track of Objects at runtime in DataGridView on cellclick event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, runtime

As per my functionality when I click on a cell in datagridview,a dialog opens.
I fill all the values in the dialog and store the dialog values into an object dynamically.

The same procedure follows for further rows.

Now how should I persist all the objects values?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where is the origin of the data that is displayed into the DataGridView?

Comment: thanks for your reply..my data is coming from oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to save them in a list

Lets say that your object's name is myObject , with properties, Id, Name and Amount

Then each time that you save the object you can add it into that list:

```
 Dim myList As New List(Of myObject)

' Fill your object with dialog values
dim tempObj as new myObject
tempObj.Id=
tempObj.Name=
tempObj.Amount=


'When you want to save the object'
 myList .Add(tempObj)
'You can do all together and avoid the creation of tempObj:
 'myList .Add(New myObject() With {.Id= 10,.Name="dad",.Amount=122})
```

You need to provide more info if you want more help.